# rclone quits FTP server after asking for UTF8

Tags: ftp, utf-8

I need to programmatically copy data from an FTP server with `rclone`.
The config is as simple as:

```
[exampleftp]
type = ftp
host = ftp.example.com
user = myuser
pass = mypass
```

If I try to copy anything, I get:

```
Failed to create file system for "exampleftp:/": NewFs: failed to make FTP connection to "ftp.example.com:21": UTF8 support on
```

Dumping the protocol exchange shows:

```
$ rclone --config=rclone.conf ls exampleftp: -vv --dump bodies

DEBUG : Using config file from "rclone.conf"
DEBUG : rclone: Version "v1.55.1-DEV" starting with parameters ["rclone" "--config=rclone.conf" "ls" "exampleftp:" "-vv" "--dump" "bodies"]
DEBUG : Creating backend with remote "exampleftp:"
DEBUG : ftp://ftp.example.com:21: Connecting to FTP server
DEBUG : FTP Rx: "220 Welcome to the example FTP Server."
DEBUG : FTP Tx: "USER myuser"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: "331 User myuser, password please"
DEBUG : FTP Tx: PASS *****
DEBUG : FTP Rx: "230 Password Ok, User logged in"
DEBUG : FTP Tx: "FEAT"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: "211- Additional features supported include:"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: " MDTM"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: " MFCT"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: " MFMT"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: " SIZE"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: " REST STREAM"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: " AUTH TLS"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: " AUTH SSL"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: " PBSZ"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: " EPRT"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: " EPSV"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: " XCRC"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: " XSHA1"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: " XSHA256"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: " XSHA512"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: " XMD5"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: " HASH SHA-256;SHA-512;SHA-1*;MD5"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: " PROT"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: " LANG EN*"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: " SITE PSWD"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: " SITE ZONE"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: " SITE UTIME"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: " MODE Z ZLIB(LEVEL)"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: " MLST Type*;Size*;Modify*;Create*;"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: " CLNT"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: " CSID"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: " RMDA"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: " UTF8"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: "211 End"
DEBUG : FTP Tx: "TYPE I"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: "200 Type Binary"
DEBUG : FTP Tx: "OPTS UTF8 ON"
DEBUG : FTP Rx: "220 UTF8 support on"
DEBUG : FTP Tx: "QUIT"
Failed to create file system for "exampleftp:": NewFs: failed to make FTP connection to "ftp.example.com:21": UTF8 support on
```

To me, this seems to say:

- Server: "I support UTF8"
- Client: "Great, then please use UTF8"
- Server: "Sure, here it is"
- Client: "Err, I need to go. Bye."

Everything works ok with another client, such as `lftp`.
However would much prefer to use `rclone`, as this would be part of a framework that is pre-configured for `rclone`.

Does anybody know what is going on and any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in the [FTP library](https://github.com/jlaffaye/ftp) used by `rclone`. The library [expects](https://github.com/jlaffaye/ftp/blob/11820403398b118877718a169d6368edc6e3ef9a/ftp.go#L430) [`200`](https://github.com/jlaffaye/ftp/blob/11820403398b118877718a169d6368edc6e3ef9a/status.go#L13) return code but your server sends `220`. You probably want to open an issue [here](https://github.com/jlaffaye/ftp/issues). Or maybe with your FTP server software vendor as [UTF-8 Option for FTP specs](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-ftpext-utf-8-option-00) lists only `200` return code as valid for a successful state.

Comment: Thanks. I actually filed a bug with rclone. The FTP library does specify that it adheres to the specs. So it cannot really be blamed. Using (and accepting) 220 seems however to be pretty common, so it is up to rclone developers to decide whether they want to be more compatible (by using a different FTP library) or more strict.